# Extract HTML pure with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

Can you with "php simple html dom" take a piece of HTML and NOT only the content?

I have trie with:

```
foreach ($html->find('div.info-bar') as $infop) {
  $info = $infop->plaintext;
}
```

Unfortunately, the output is:

> Level 24 Trophies 4201 Bronze 2725 Silver 1057 Gold 341 Platinum 78
>   Level 24 66 66 %

While I would like to extract the pure HTML..

This is my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://my.playstation.com/obaidmiz04');
foreach ($html->find('div.info-bar') as $infop) {
  $info = $infop->plaintext;
}
echo $info;
```

Comment: you probably want to add the string to the `$info` variable, not overwriting it. So use `.=` instead of `=` in the loop.

Comment: I tried, but continues to print only the text and not the html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$escapedHtmlChars = "";
$htmlElements = "";
$html = file_get_html('https://my.playstation.com/obaidmiz04');
foreach ($html->find('div.info-bar') as $infop) {
  //You can see html characters in text
  //This shows you html codes, not for using
  $escapedHtmlChars .= htmlspecialchars($infop); 
  //You can see html elements
  $htmlElements .= $infop;
  //You can see only text in selected element
  $plainText .= $infop->plaintext;
}
echo $plainText;
echo "<br /> <br />";
echo $escapedHtmlChars;
echo "<br /> <br />";
echo $htmlElements;
```

plaintext method returns only text in selected element.